# breaking up <pre> text to lines of key/value

Tags: php, text, domdocument

I have the the following HTML string.

```
<div id="mydiv">
<pre>
Some content several lines. 

   Field1: value 2
   Field2: value 2
   Field3: value 3

Some content. several lines.
</pre>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the text within the `<pre>` tags and break it down to its fields, so I'm using `DomDocument()` `loadHTML()` `DOMXPath` and `query('//pre')` to get the text content of `<pre>`.

When I `var_dump` its `nodeValue` I get formatted text just as it if were displayed using `<pre>`. I'm not sure why that's the case, but I'm wondering if this can somehow help me break up the text to fields/values.

Comment: You only want the lines that have a semi-colon seperator? Discard all others?

Comment: Why is the content formatted like this? Are you creating it or are you grabbing it from an external source like this?

Comment: @pthurmond They're old HTML files that are being re-created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to read it in then just do it like this.

```
<?php
$preStr = ""; //Holds the pre-string.
$preArr = explode("\n", $preStr);
$pairs = array();

foreach ($preArr AS $line) {
  $line = trim($line);

  if (stristr($line, ':')) {
    list($key, $value) = explode(':', $line);
    $pairs[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```